# Can my bitcoins get stolen?

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, security

I posted a question on here about my bitcoins being stuck, they are no longer stuck but someone has taken all of my bitcoins from that wallet and I don't know how

Comment: What do you mean stuck , and what do you mean stolen ? What kind of wallet are you using ? How did you conclude they were stolen ? Please update the question before we assume the worst.

Comment: Well I posted a question here the other day explaining how they got stuck, the address changed half way through I think, I am using etherum and they were there and then a few transactions came through that were this week but dated April

Comment: Please clarify what website, exactly what you did, what you see, and what you expect to seem. As stated, I vote to close the question as unclear.

Comment: @CalMO'Gorman-Anderson:  Addresses do not change mid-way in a transaction. Ethereum and bitcoin are two different platforms and are not interchangeable. +1 to close, as i have no idea what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question , yes. If some one has access to your private keys, then it is easy to steal them and more or less there is no way to get them back.